# Kafka connection with Flink is not working only with YARN deployment

Tags: apache-kafka, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn, apache-flink

I developped a simple Flink job which consumes a Kafka stream. All is working great on local environment. But when I try to run my Flink job on my cluster with YARN, nothing is coming. (And, I don't have any error message).

```
./bin/flink run -m yarn-cluster -yn 4 /Flink/Flink_Stream_Kafka/jar-with-dependencies.jar --server X.X.X.X:9092 --topic logs
```

I have of course checked if my cluster had access to the stream and it has. I can even run my job as a simple java program on each machine of my cluster and it works.

Any insights to explain this ?

Thank you

**EDIT :**

```
object KafkaConsuming {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {


    // Flink parameter tool
    // Allow to pass arguments to this script
    val params: ParameterTool = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args)

    // set up streaming execution environment
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    // make parameters available globally
    env.getConfig.setGlobalJobParameters(params)

    val properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", params.get("server"));

    // only requied for Kafka 0.8
    //properties.rsetProperty("zookeeper.connect", "X.X.X.X:2181");

    val stream: DataStream[String] = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer010[String](params.get("topic"), new SimpleStringSchema(), properties))

    //stream.print()

    val logs: DataStream[MinifiedLog] = stream.map(x => LogParser2.parse(x))

    val sessions = logs.map { x => (x.timestamp, x.sent, 1l)}

    val sessionCnt: DataStream[(Long, Long, Long)] = sessions
      // key stream by sensorId
      .keyBy(2)
      // tumbling time window of 1 minute length
      .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(10)))  
      .reduce( (x: (Long, Long, Long), y: (Long, Long, Long)) => (x._1, x._2 + y._2, x._3 + y._3))
      .map { z => (z._1, z._2 / 10, z._3 / 10)}

     sessionCnt.print()

    env.execute("Kafka consuming")

  }
}
```

Comment: How are you checking if data is arriving on the cluster?

Comment: I run a kafka consumer on it and I was receiving the stream.
`bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh –bootstrap-server X.X.X.X:9092 –topic log –from-beginning`

Comment: Can you post the code of your Flink application?

Comment: Yes, I edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `sessionCnt.print()` will be written to the standard output on the TaskManagers.

On YARN, the easiest way to access that output is to retrieve all logs using the aggregated YARN logs (`yarn logs -applicationId <appid>`).

I'm not sure if the access to standard out files in the Flink UI works correctly.

Another way of checking if data arrives is using the Flink Web UI.

Comment: I did not think about a standard output issue. I effectively have data arriving in the Flink Web UI. I will invistigate the way to get back the output. Thank you.